# Curries as receptors of odor transfer in refrigirators

Tags: refrigerator, smell

Odor transfer is common phenomenon that occurs in refrigerators when we place items close to each other.

Since the space is less in my refrigerator,I need to keep things near to each other. Although there are some tips for arranging at distance or using proper vessels, I am interested in knowing whether curries are good receptors of odor in refrigerators or not?

Does it depends on the type of curry placed in the refrigerator?

Comment: AFAIK foods don't need to be closer to each other, just _being in the fridge_ can be enough for odor transfer - it's an enclosed box where air stays trapped just recirculating.

Comment: I would have thought of a curry as more of a transmitter than receiver of odours. Air-tight containers are your saviour. Where I live you get one free with every take-away curry;) [now they've all stopped using aluminium which though technically recyclable is not recycled after food use.]